# React big Calender show more in custom event component is not showing

Tags: react-big-calendar

I have made a customized event component for events , If in a day I have multiple events the show more is not displaying in moth view  . It shows when I remove the custom component and work as well .The +more component also shows +2 more when i resize the fonts of events and there are more than 2 events   ,but here i want it to show  only one event and remaining in +more
If you know any solution please help

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import AllEvents from "./events";

const CustomizeEvent = ({
  event,
  onEdit,
  onDelete,
  edit,
  onSave,
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(event.title);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="custom-event">
      {edit === event.id ? (
        <>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id=""
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={() => onSave(event.id, value)}>save </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <strong>{event.title}</strong>
          <div>{event.description}</div>
          <button onClick={() => onEdit(event)}>edit </button>
          <button onClick={() => onDelete(event)}>Delete </button>{" "}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

const CustomToolbar = ({ label, onView, onNavigate }) => {
  return (
    <div className="custom-toolbar d-flex ">
      <div></div>
      <div className="d-flex">
        <button onClick={() => onNavigate("PREV")}>Previous</button>
        <h2>{label}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => onNavigate("NEXT")}>Next</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => onView("month")}>Month</button>
        <button onClick={() => onView("week")}>Week</button>
        <button onClick={() => onView("day")}>Day</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const MyCalendar = () => {
  const [event, setEvents] = useState(AllEvents);
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(-1);

  const handleEventClick = (event) => {
    console.log("event clicked");
  };

  const handleEventSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    console.log("selected slot ", selectInfo);
  };

  const handleEdit = (eventDetail) => {
    console.log("eventDetail.id", eventDetail.id);
    setEdit(eventDetail.id);
  };

  const handleDelete = (eventDetail) => {
    console.log(eventDetail, "deleted");
    const EditedEvents = event.filter((item) => item.id !== eventDetail.id);
    setEvents(EditedEvents);
    console.log(EditedEvents);
  };

  const handleSave = (eventId, eventTitle) => {
    const EditedEvents = event.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === eventId) {
        item.title = eventTitle;
      }
      return item;
    });
    setEvents(EditedEvents);
    setEdit(-1);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500 }}>
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={event}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        onSelectSlot={handleEventSelect}
        dayPropGetter={CustomDayPropGetter}
        onSelectEvent={handleEventClick}
        showAllEvents={false}
        components={{
          event: (props) => (
            <CustomizeEvent
              {...props}
              onEdit={handleEdit}
              onDelete={handleDelete}
              edit={edit}
              onSave={handleSave}
              allEvents={event}
            />
          ),
          toolbar: CustomToolbar
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyCalendar;
const CustomDayPropGetter = (date) => {
  const day = date.getDay();
  if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
    return {
      className: "weekend-day",
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "black"
      }
    };
  }

  return {};
};
```